# How to get a collision-free path in a known map with move_base?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, global-planner, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I would like to use the global planner only to compute a **collision-free path from pose A to pose B** for a rectangular robot from a .png map (To be precise, I mean a [nav_msgs/Path Message](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html)). I ran a map server using:

```
rosrun map_server map_server map.yml
```

where `map.yml` is:

```
image: 1st_Floor.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

I used the information on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server. Now I would like map_server to publish on a `global_costmap`, as shown there: http://wiki.ros.org/move_base, which in turn should publish on a `global_planner`.
I don't really understand how to initialize `costmap_2d` and `global_planner` and what other things I should do.

Can anybody tell me what I am supposed to do? Basically, I would like to do something similar to what is shown on the [global_planner documentation page](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner).

**[EDIT]**

I tried David Lu's answer:

1st console:

```
roslauch my_planner.launch
```

2nd console:

```
rosrun map_server map_server map.yml
```

Finally, I get:

1st console:

```
...
[ INFO] [1532441256.591719189]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1532441256.603717786]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1532441410.809228149]: Resizing costmap to 942 X 850 at 0.100000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1532441410.908177209]: Received a 942 X 850 map at 0.100000 m/pix
```

2nd console:

```
[ INFO] [1532441410.480988502]: Loading map from image "./1st_Floor.png"
[ INFO] [1532441410.500530096]: Read a 942 X 850 map @ 0.100 m/cell
```

It seems OK but when I use `rosservice call /gp/make_plan "..."`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

and in 1st console:

```
[gp-2] process has died [pid 14912, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/global_planner/planner __name:=gp __log:=/home/loic/.ros/log/5cecac24-8f4e-11e8-83cf-843a4b9cdf04/gp-2.log].
```

**[EDIT 2]**

I tried with a white map to be sure that the start and goal poses are on the map but that didn't work, so I think something is missing for the planner to work properly. Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298059/how-to-get-a-collision-free-path-in-a-known-map-with-move_base?/) by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [planner node](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/global_planner/src/plan_node.cpp) included with the global_planner package to do this.

Here's a launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="gp" pkg="global_planner" type="planner" output="screen">
  <rosparam>
  costmap:
    plugins:
      - {name: 'static_layer', type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
  </rosparam>
  </node>
  <node name="static_tf" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_link 100"/>
</launch>
```

This provides the `navfn::MakePlan` service which you can call like this:

```
rosservice call /gp/make_plan "start:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: '/map'
  pose:
    position:
      x: 1.0
      y: 1.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
goal:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: '/map'
  pose:
    position:
      x: 5.0
      y: 1.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0"
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-07-24**:
Thanks for the answer. I ran the launch file you gave me and then the map server and it seemed to work but when I call the service I get an error. I edited the question.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-07-24**:
Did you send it coordinates inside your map?

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-07-24**:
I'm not really sure how the coordinates work (cells, pixel, ...), so I don't know how to get valid poses. So I just tried with a 942x850 completely white image. I gave the same coordinates as you did and got the same error.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-07-24**:
What happens if you change the start x position to 1.0?

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-07-24**:
It displays the same error. Have you been able to run it?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-07-27**:
I've duplicated your blank map and changed the coordinates above to reflect valid coordinates. There's some weird stuff with the hard coded frame_ids in the melodic version of the plan_node, but other than that, it works fine.

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-08-01**:
Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I was very busy. I changed the coordinates and it works. Now I'm wondering: how can I change the dimensions of my robot? I have currently no idea of when my robot is considered to be in collision with an obstacle on the map.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-08-01**:
Excellent! Please mark this question as correct with the checkmark to the left.

You should check out http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Inflation for more info on changing the dimensions, and if you have further questions, open a new question here. Best of luck!